# Websphere MQ - Java application - enable logging

Tags: java, logging, jms, ibm-mq

I'm using a java application that connects to Websphere MQ. I tried enabling Logging by setting the log level to DEBUG for the package `com.ibm.mq`. However, it does not log anything. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you give a little more background to the issue that you have please?

General approach to debug is

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031850_.htm?lang=en

and

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031310_.htm

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is enable logging in your own application and output completion code and reason codes from ALL MQ API calls.

MQ for Java:

```
catch (MQException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.err.println("compCode=" +  e.completionCode + " : reasonCode=" + e.reasonCode);
}
```

or for JMS applications, retrieve the LinkedException and output the information.

```
catch (JMSException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();

   if (e.getLinkedException() != null)
   {
      JMSLinkedException jle = new JMSLinkedException(e.getLinkedException());
      System.err.println("compCode=" +  jle.getMQCompletionCode() + " : reasonCode=" + jle.getMQReasonCode());
   }
}
```